# Generating a row if there is not a matching id in another table as a placeholder row

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 tables. Table 1 has a foreign key of factor_id in Table 2.

Table 1 - Financial Data

```
factor_id  trans_id  profit(in K) 
    1        476         24
    2        476         22  
    3        476         19
    3        515         41
```

Table 2 - Financial Factors

```
factor_id  model_id  factor_title
    1         43        domestic  
    2         43        foreign
    3         43        3rd party
    4         43        licensed
```

What I need is for Table 1 to return all 3 rows for model_id 43 and trans_id 476 AND IN ADDITION a placeholder row for the one that is missing with factor_id 4 since it doesn't exist in Table 1

Expected output would be:

```
factor_id   trans_id   profit(in K)
    1         476          24
    2         476          22
    3         476          19
    4         476          0  <---Created output Row that doesn't exist in Table 1
```

Comment: And show us your expected results.

Comment: This is flagged as two questions, but its only one, can it be done and how to go about it is practically a single request

Answer (score 0):

You could use an OUTER JOIN, either *LEFT* or *RIGHT*. This type of join will return all records from one table (the *FROM* table for a *LEFT* or the *JOIN* table for a *RIGHT*) even if there are not no matches in the other table, a null value will be returned in all columns referenced from the table that has no matches but are returned in the results.

To return a zero or other value instead of a *NULL* we can use the `ISNULL()` function.

The following two queries are equivalent, Showing a *RIGHT* join first, (the term *OUTER* is optional and omitted from this example) as it matches the `FROM` statement that you may already have, the *LEFT* join example swaps the tables around in the statement. In general the `FROM` table should be the one that the most significant *filtering* will be performed on, for this limited example neither is superior to the other.

```
SELECT ff.factor_id, IsNull(f.trans_id,476) AS trans_id, IsNull(f.profit,0) AS profit
FROM financial_data f 
RIGHT JOIN financial_data ff on ff.factor_id = f.factor_id
```

*LEFT* variant:

```
SELECT ff.factor_id, IsNull(f.trans_id,476) AS trans_id, IsNull(f.profit,0) AS profit
FROM financial_factors ff 
LEFT JOIN financial_data f on ff.factor_id = f.factor_id
```

Results:

| factor_id | trans_id | profit |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 476 | 24 |
| 2 | 476 | 22 |
| 3 | 476 | 19 |
| 4 | 476 | 0 |

Defaulting a column to zero is pretty safe, however defaulting to a specific value really should only be done in conjunction with filtering, so I assume the default of `trans_id=476` is because this is the filter you are applying to the tables, in which case the following parameterised query might be more useful:

```
DECLARE @transId INT = 476

SELECT ff.factor_id
     , IsNull(f.trans_id, @transId) AS trans_id
     , IsNull(f.profit, 0) AS profit
FROM financial_data f 
RIGHT JOIN financial_data ff on ff.factor_id = f.factor_id
WHERE f.trans_id = @transId;
```

You could also use a `UNION` between two separate queries, if you can construct a query to represent the *missing* rows, in this case however an OUTER JOIN is likely to be the simpler approach.

Answer (score -1):

I think you just want `left join`:

```
select ff.factor_id, v.trans_id, coalesce(f.profit, 0) as profit
from financial_factors ff cross join
     (values (476)) v(trans_id) left join
     financial f
     on f.factor_id = ff.factor_id and
        f.trans_id = v.trans_id;
```

Comment: `model_id` should not be part of the join criteria, this will output different columns to what OP has requested and it does not address how to fill the expected values for the _missing_ records.

Comment: @ChrisSchaller . . . I see that.  I misread the question and just updated the answer.